# My PC logs out accidently when hit enter from Chrome addressbar after some time period

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS operating system.

I'm using Google Chrome Browser Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) for Internet surfing.

My problem is when I hit enter in address bar(Chrome address bar) after type some keyword for Google search it accidentally logs out Ubuntu user. After log in I have to start all the tools/softwares from scratch. And it takes time.

**Note :** It does not happen every time when hit enter. It happens 2-3 times in a day.

Can any one knows what is the problem behind it? Please let me know if you know anything about it or need more information.

Comment: Chrome 46 is really old now, you should update. However I'm not sure if that will help.

Comment: @spacelander Yeah, step 1 of troubleshooting this will be to update Chrome. Then if the issue continues we will proceed.

Comment: @spacelander, wjandrea, thanks for the comment. I have updated chrome version to 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit). One day is passed without any issue. I'll wait for one week hopefully to see it works perfectly.